# Predicting the outcome of a two-player game with only one end-game statistic

Tags: bayesian, modeling, supervised-learning, games

I'm trying to create a supervised learning model for a two player game where there are no statistics recorded except the outcome of the match.

I came up with the following Bayes' net:

[image]

Where $X_i^{t_i} \in {\rm I\!R}$ is the *rating* (some made up variable to keep track of how good players are) of player $i$ after they've played $t_i \in \{0,1,...\}$ games, and $G_{i,j}^{t_{i,j}} \in \{0, 1\}$ is the outcome of the game (1 if player $i$ wins, 0 otherwise), after $i$ and $j$ have played $t_{i,j} \in \{0,1,...\}$ games together.

So, my use case would be, given the outcome of every match thus far, predict the outcome of the next match, $G_{i,j}^{t_{i,j}+1}$.

I have two questions:

Number one, is inference on this Bayes' net the best way to solve my problem? Two, if it is, how do I do inference on a Bayes' net with continuous and discrete variables?

Comment: If you're already in the business of rating players over time, maybe you can short-circuit the formality and just fit a linear regression to the gap in rating. AFAIK this is similar to how [cMax](http://www.row2k.com/polls/index.cfm?cat=college&ID=551&type=cMax%20Rankings) is computed.

Comment: @ssdecontrol You're probably right. That's a whole lot simpler than looking at the Bayes' net.

Comment: One interesting discussion of a simple rating system with continuous variables is the 538's ELI ranking system that only use margin of victory and a binary for home/away http://fivethirtyeight.com/datalab/nfl-elo-ratings-are-back/

Comment: Also, this particular net wouldn't give you the prediction of the game "given the outcome of every match thus far". The outcome of the game would be a function *only* of scores at time t.